# Jquery Chaining on different link

Tags: javascript, jquery, chain

Basically what I want to achieve is when I mouseenter the "first a" link, the link on the second will turn red, when I mouseout it should return to blue, but I cant seem to target it using `$('this')`.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.shareButtonsWrapper div a:first-child', function(){
    $(this).parent().$(".shareButtonsWrapper div a:last-child").css({"color":"red"});
}).on('mouseleave', '.shareButtonsWrapper div a:first-child', function(){
    $(this).parent().$(".shareButtonsWrapper div a:last-child").css({"color":"blue"});
});
```

[**Example Here.**](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/LsqaC)

Comment: have a look at JSbin http://jsbin.com/OhutAxu/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this JSbin.

http://jsbin.com/OhutAxu/2/edit

```
$("a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next().css('color', 'red');
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).next().css('color', 'blue');
    }
);
```

You need to use JQuery .next() function in order to access next element.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var link = '.shareButtonsWrapper div a:first';
$('body').on('mouseenter', link, function(){
    $(this).next('a').css({"color":"red"});
}).on('mouseleave', link, function(){
    $(this).next('a').css({"color":"blue"});
});
```

[**CodePan Example.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ieLzw)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.shareButtonsWrapper div a:first-child').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).siblings().css("color","red");
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).siblings().css("color", "blue");
});
```

You may use the next() function instead of the siblings().

Comment: If you look at the code that OP has posted, you shall see that mine is not much complex.

Comment: I agree. But 'not much complex' != 'simple'